# How to get number of friends for a user in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Given a table `users_groups`

| userId | groupId |
| --- | --- |
| userA | groupOne |
| userA | groupTwo |
| userA | groupThree |
| userB | groupOne |
| userC | groupOne |
| userD | groupTwo |

How do I find the number of friends for each user, where a friend is defined as a someone in the same group as a user?

| userId | numFriends |
| --- | --- |
| userA | 3 |
| userB | 2 |
| userC | 2 |
| userD | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the table to itself, and count them:

```
select Me.UserId,  count(Friends.UserId)  as Friends
from user_groups as Me
     left join
     user_groups as Friends
     on Me.groupId=Friends.groupId
     and Me.userId<>Friends.userId
group by Me.UserId
```

Beware though, this can count the same user more than once if the user is related to the current user via more than one group. You might like to change to count(distinct Friends,UserId), if you don't want that.